# Solr plugin custom

Tags: java, search, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

In Hybris Solr, how do I develop my custom plugin? I want to develop my own filter, but the Eclipse IDE can not find TokenFilter under org.apache.lucene*, it does not
recognize org.apache.lucene*. Thanks

With filter, I mean the filter that can be added to an analyzer of a fieldType.
Is it a configuration to be done in Eclipse of something to download?

Comment: When you say filter do you mean to customize the way that solr performs the queries to add your own clauses?

Comment: I mean the filters used in a fieldType within schema.xml file.

Comment: can anyone help me?